# Using the definition of limit to prove $\frac{(n^3)+(-1)^n 3n^2 + 1}{n^3 + 2n^2 + (-1)^n}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to prove that $\frac{(n^3)+(-1)^n 3n^2 + 1}{n^3 + 2n^2 + (-1)^n}$ converges using the definition of limits. Let's say it converges to some $\mathcal{l}$. I know that:

$\text{Let } \epsilon > 0$, and let N = (some value of $\epsilon$ to be determined). Then $\forall n > N$, we have:

$| \frac{(n^3)+(-1)^n 3n^2 + 1}{n^3 + 2n^2 + (-1)^n} - \mathcal{l} |$

And I know we want to show that:

$| \frac{(n^3)+(-1)^n 3n^2 + 1}{n^3 + 2n^2 + (-1)^n} - \mathcal{l} | < \text{ (some n) } < \text{ (some N) } = \epsilon$

But how do I solve this without knowing where it converges to? If I had to warrant a guess, I'd say the fraction converges to 0.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It converges to 1...collect in the numerator and denominator $n^3$